# JavaScript Closure Memory Leak

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, google-chrome-devtools

I have a Javascript garbage collection/memory leak question. I'm using Chrome 28.0.1500.71 on OS X 10.8.4.

The following code never deallocates the space that was held by `me` and I'm clueless as to why.

```
var MyClass = function() {
    this.x = 1;

    var self = this;
    this.do_thing = function() {
        self.x++;
    };
};
MyClass.prototype.destroy = function() {
    delete this.do_thing;
};

var me = new MyClass();
me.do_thing();
me.destroy();
me = null;

// the MyClass object formerly known as 'me' is still allocated here
// (as evidenced by Chrome's heap profiler)
```

Chrome seems to keep the object created by the expression `new MyClass()` (the object that `me` pointed to before being set to `null`) in memory because it is referenced by `self` in the call to `me.do_thing()`. However, I would have thought the call to `destroy()`, which unsets `me.do_thing` would throw away the variables in the scope of the constructor (`self` in the `new MyClass()` call).

I have also tried using Underscore.JS's `_.bind` function but run into the same unresolved problem described here: [Instances referenced by 'bound_this' only are not garbage collected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576372/instances-referenced-by-bound-this-only-are-not-garbage-collected).

Comment: Please be precise and differentiate between "the global variable `me`" and "the `MyClass` object". The variable will surely remain in memory, but that's not a problem (and if it is, you can remove it from `window`, see simonleung's answer). Does Chrome indicate that the `MyClass` object is still alive?

Comment: Fair point; it's the `MyClass` object that *was* referenced by `me` that never gets deallocated. I updated the wording of my question to make this clearer.

Comment: Looks like there is a bug in V8, I opened an issue against this: https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2791

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it is not garbage collected, but adding the destroy method to the instance instead of the prototype and setting `self` to null, will apparently work:

```
var MyClass = function() {
    this.x = 1;

    var self = this;
    this.do_thing = function() {
        self.x++;
    };

    this.destroy = function() {
        delete this.do_thing;
        self = null;
    };
};

var me = new MyClass();
me.do_thing();
me.destroy();
me = null;
```

Comment: Interesting, although I'm still curious why `self` needs to be manually disposed of

Comment: @soney it seems like it has something to do with the assignment of `self.x` in the line `self.x++`. If you change that line to `return self.x`, it also will get garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

me is still a property of window object even you set it to null. Thus "me" is still in the memory.

I think this may help:

```
window.me = new MyClass();
me.do_thing();
delete window.me;
```

Comment: This snippet still leaves the `MyClass` object allocated in my browser.

Answer (score 0):

MyClass is a global variable. It is also a property of window object in browser environment. It is not a garbage so of couse it will not be collected.

Comment: While the `MyClass` function is taking up space, I'm referring to the object created by the expression `new MyClass()`. After `me` is set to null, it shouldn't have any more references to it and should be collected.

Comment: the object will be collected by the gc, just not immediately. Try to refresh and genrate a new heap snapshot, you will not see any MyClass object.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug.
Btw me.destroy() is not necessary. It should be deleted without it.